# ASP error Server.CreateObject with new server IIS7/WS2008

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

Getting an error when migrating an old ASP script to a new box.  The old server was IIS6, Windows Server 2003.  The new server is IIS7, Windows Server 2008.  Here's the error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
Server.CreateObject Failed
/img.asp, line 39
800401f3
```

The offending line is

```
set download = Server.CreateObject("csFileDownload.Binfile")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two things that jump out right away:

1. You may not have enabled ASP in IIS7 http://forums.iis.net/t/1007530.aspx
2. You need to register the COM object that contains the csFileDownload.Binfile class by calling `regsvr32 path to dll` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Is the csFileDownload.Binfile component installed and registered on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Register the DLL or the COM object

Add permissions to the IIS user to this DLL

Then do this:

- Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\
  FeatureControl\FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701
- Note If the FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701 subkey does not exist, you must manually create it. If you're using a 64 bit OS, you may need to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\ FeatureControl\FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701 instead
- Right-click FEATURE_IGNORE_ZONES_INITIALIZATION_FAILURE_KB945701,
  point to New, and then click DWORD Value
- Type w3wp.exe to name the new registry entry, and then press ENTER.
- Right-click w3wp.exe, and then click Modify.
- In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.

After setting this registry key, a simple app pool restart will apply the change. No longer will your .NET COM components randomly stop working with no real solution except shuffling application pools!